# .NET 3.5 CE Deployment

Tags: .net, compact-framework

I have an C#.NET application for pocket PC. Application needs .NET3.5 framework to run on device. If I deploy the application through VS2008 by connecting device through ActiveSync then it deploys framework also. Is there any way if I can deploy framework without VS2008???

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the procedure I used to put framework on pocket PC device:

**http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E3821449-3C6B-42F1-9FD9-0041345B3385&displaylang=en** link can be used to download .NET3.5 Framework msi file. I downloaded the .msi file and as written in installation procedure on microsoft website, I tried running the msi file after connecting my device to my computer using ActiveSync 4.0. But still msi installed on my computer rather than the device. So fix was to copy the cab file manually to device and run it from there. **NETCFv35.ppc.armv4.cab** is the file for pocket pc as ppc mentioned in file name, this file can be found at installation location on the computer in my case it was (may be default) **C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\CompactFramework\v3.5\WindowsCE** folder. Then I copied this cab file to device using active sync then running the cab file on device will install the framework.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=E3821449-3C6B-42F1-9FD9-0041345B3385&displaylang=en